# Django: BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] write could not complete without blocking

Tags: python, django

I have django project:

In have a view which updates some values

In the view i have few `print` commands

I am trying to run the same url using curl multiple times

like eg:

```
curl "127.0.0.1:8000/update?var=somevalue001"
curl "127.0.0.1:8000/update?var=somevalue002"
.
.
.
.
.
.
curl "127.0.0.1:8000/update?var=somevalue100"
```

But after 40 times running it starts giving the error

`BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] write could not complete without blocking`

How to avoid it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948375/setting-stdout-to-non-blocking-in-python

Comment: can you explain a bit also